# How to add timespan values in list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

In the below code i will get a list of time span values. I need to add all the time span values and that value has to be stored in string.How to achieve this i tried a lot but I can't find answer for this.
Thanks in Advance.

```
  List<TimeSpan> objList = new List<TimeSpan>();
        string  totalIntervalTime = string.Empty;
     private void Resume_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
                {
                    textBox3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                    //objPausetmr.Tick += new EventHandler(objPausetmr_Tick);
                    //objPausetmr.Stop();
                    tmrObj.Start();
                    DateTime pausetime = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox2.Text);
                    DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox3.Text);
                    TimeSpan difference = pausetime - startTime;
                    string intervalDifference = difference.ToString();
                    richTextBox1.Text = intervalDifference;

                    TimeSpan tltTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
                    objList.Add(difference);
                    foreach (TimeSpan tmVal in objList)
                    {
                        tltTime.Add(tmVal);
                    }
                    totalIntervalTime = tltTime.ToString();

                    //MessageBox.Show(interval_Time.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please set the Pause time");
                }
            }
```

Comment: what difficulty you are facing to do so ?

Comment: Not quite sure what it is you want to achieve, what is it about your code that is not working? Please hilight the part that is giving you exceptions, not working as expected, etc.

Comment: @Sander tmVal is not added to tltTime.  The string totalIntervalTime  value is zero

Comment: @Vignesh take a look at the answers given, as Alexei says the Add method of DateTime and TimeSpan will return a new instance of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to add values of all time spans into single time span.

`DateTime` and `TimeSpan` are immutable structs. All operations using them return new instances. So you need to store result of operation in a TimeSpan value (normally just updating exisintg one is fine)

```
  var totalTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
  foreach (TimeSpan currentValue in objList)
  {
       totalTime = totalTime + currentValue;
  }
```

Usage of `+` covered in details in [TimeSpan.Addition Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.op_addition.aspx) MSDN article.

Alternatively you can use [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var totalTime = objList.Aggregate(
      (accumulatedValue,current) => accumulatedValue + current);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
string s = String.Join(",",objList.Select(x => x.ToString()));
```

Have a look at

[String.Join Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx)

[Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx)

Using `objList.Select(x => x.ToString())` you can determine the format output you want

[Span.ToString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)