# How to sum a DateTime DataTable field with Linq

Tags: linq, datetime, datatable, sum

I have a DataTable that has a column "MYDate" with these values:

00:10:44
00:12:05
01:12:07
00:22:29
02:06:47

I need to SUM all these values as datetime to obtain this: 04:04:12
How can I do this using Linq?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add timespan values in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358945/how-to-add-timespan-values-in-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your column type is `TimeSpan`, then it is as simple as

```
TimeSpan total = TimeSpan.FromTicks(dt
                               .AsEnumerable()
                               .Sum(r => r.Field<TimeSpan>("MYDate").Ticks));
```

If you have string values as `TimeSpan`, then you have to parse it using [`TimeSpan.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse.aspx) or [`TimeSpan.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) depending on your requirement and data. Like

```
TimeSpan total = TimeSpan.FromTicks(dt
                      .AsEnumerable()
                      .Sum(r => TimeSpan.Parse(r.Field<string>("MYDate")).Ticks));
```

Comment: if i want to add Group by and need handle null values? How can i achive this?